# How to add an Authorization header to a HTTP request with file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, api, http

As the title says I’m having trouble making a signed HTTP request for an OAuth 1.0a protected file.
I am trying to use the file_get_contents method for the request an want to add the Authorization header by using the stream_context_create() method. [Sourcecode below]

```
$url = "https://rest.immobilienscout24.de/restapi/api/offer/v1.0/user/me/realestate";
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: OAuth
            oauth_consumer_key = \"MY_KEY\”,
            oauth_token = \"MY_TOKEN\"
            oauth_signature_method= \"HMAC-SHA1\",
            oauth_timestamp=\"TIMESTAMP\",
            oauth_nonce=\"MY_NONCE\",
            oauth_signature=\"MY_SIGNATURE\""
        )
    ));
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

This is how the request should look like

```
GET /api/file HTTP/1.1 Host: example.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="KEY",
    oauth_token="TOKEN",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp="TIMESTAMP",
    oauth_nonce="NONCE",
    oauth_signature="SIGNATURE"
```

Problem: I always get the following Error:
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in line XX.
What am I doing wrong? Is it creating the header?
I know this can be done with curl also but I have literally no knowledge nor experience using curl.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OAuth 1.0a spec](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#auth_header)

> The OAuth Protocol Parameters are sent in the Authorization header the following way:
>
> 1. Parameter names and values are encoded per [Parameter Encoding](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#encoding_parameters).
> 2. For each parameter, the name is immediately followed by an '=' character (ASCII code 61), a '"' character (ASCII code 34), the parameter value (MAY be empty), and another '"' character (ASCII code 34).
> 3. Parameters are separated by a comma character (ASCII code 44) and OPTIONAL linear whitespace per **[[RFC2617](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#RFC2617)]**.
> 4. The OPTIONAL realm parameter is added and interpreted per **[[RFC2617](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#RFC2617)]**, section 1.2.

One issue is that you're inserting `\n` (*LF*) characters into your header string, which isn't allowed according to RFC2617. You also seem to be missing a comma after you `oauth_token`. It's also unclear if you're properly encoding your parameters.

I think an easier way to avoid making these mistakes could be to either use something like [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http-build-query) and pass `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` as the **enc_type** paremeter to be compliant with [RFC3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which is what OAuth 1.0a states it follows, or you could just set the parameters in a separate array and [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map) to encode them yourself.

```
$params = [
    "realm"                  => $realm, /* optional */
    "oauth_consumer_key"     => $key,
    "oauth_token"            => $token,
    "oauth_signature_method" => $sigmeth,
    "oauth_timestamp"        => $timestamp,
    "oauth_nonce"            => $nonce,
    "oauth_signature"        => $sig,
];
```

## option 1

```
/* This will give you the proper encoded string to include in your Authorization header */
$params = http_build_query($params, null, ',', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);    

$opts = ["http" => ["header" => "Authorization: OAuth " . $params]];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

## option 2

```
$params = implode(',',array_map(function($v,$k) {
    return $k . '="' . rawurlencode($v) . '"';
}, $params, array_keys($params)));

$opts = ["http" => ["header" => "Authorization: OAuth " . $params]];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I think option 2 is actually more compliant with OAuth 1, because `http_build_query` won't quote the parameters. [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) will be compliant with RFC3986 which should help keep your values properly encoded.

Comment: Thank you! I have to provide them in the Authorization Header.
Still got the same error.
Is there a possibility to see the request my xampp-server sended? Maybe I could find the error then...

Comment: Sorry, I never actually read the OAuth 1.0 spec before. I didn't think anyone was still using OAuth1, but after a quick review I've revised my answer to more aptly address your questions. It's specific to OAuth1. I was just reply as though this was a general HTTP question.

Comment: Thanks again! I tested both options. still same error.
Would I get the same Error if my Keys & Signature would be wrong?

Comment: I would suspect so. [According to the spec](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#rfc.section.10): "_When the Service Provider rejects a Consumer request, it SHOULD respond with HTTP 400 Bad Request or HTTP 401 Unauthorized._". It lists __Invalid signature__ and __Invalid Consumer Key__ as some of the reasons, among others, for a 401 response code. But __Unsupported signature method__ is listed as 400. So that might narrow it down for you just a bit.